# Lower than low level common bsd sockets

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

How do you do low low level sockets in C, example: actually sending a SYN.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you actually want is a raw socket ... you can completely control the headers and flags with the raw socket interface, but programming them is much more challenging.  Here's a great tutorial to get you started: http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~steflik/cs455/rawip.txt.

Comment: given link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Raw sockets are your friend.

There have been some links to useful information [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110341/tcp-handshake-with-sockraw-socket).

Also consult Chapter 25 "Raw sockets" of Steven's "Unix Network Programming"

If you're attempting cross platform code you may find [libpcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libpcap) a useful alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [raw sockets](http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html).  In *nix, you need to be root to be able to create raw sockets.  I'm not sure if it's possible in Windows.

Comment: it's possible and you have to be administrator(or system) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the nmap sources would be an excellent place to look.