# Is it possible to manually perform a tcp 3 way handshake using nping?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, nmap

I can send a tcp syn, and I receive a syn/ack back, but at that point linux sends a tcp rst because it was not linux tcp that opened the connection.

I'm wondering if I can stop the rst, or if there's another way to manually perform the handshake so I can send arbitrary packets after it.

I'm implementing a nat for a class and I'm trying to debug more effectively.

Answer (score 2):

The discussion surrounding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110341/tcp-handshake-with-sock-raw-socket) is probably helpful.

If you are doing this for experimental reasons (i.e. not trying to interact with real tcp services) I would recommend that you set the protocol number to 253-254 instead of the regular 6 for tcp, that should allow you to prevent the kernel from picking up on the packets that you are generating.